# Enable cross origin for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have 2 subdomains, `av.xyz.example` and `video.xyz.example`. I want to enable CORS for `video.xyz.example` on `av.xyz.example`.

I have added the following code snippet in the apache configuration file of `av.xyz.com`

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "video.xyz.example"`
```

But I get the following error

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'video.xyz.example'. Origin 'https://video.xyz.example' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried doing it with `*` and still got an error that it is not permissible for a wildcard, tried doing it using - `^(.*\.xyz\.example)$` and still got the error, invalid value.

What should be the correct value in my scenario?

Comment: A CORS origin requires a valid protocol which you haven't provided. For example, `http://video.xyz.example` and `https://video.xyz.example` are two different origins. See answer below https://serverfault.com/a/923220/202676

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I was able to solve it using this code

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https?://(www\.)?(xyz\.com|video\.xyz\.com)(:\d+)?$" ACAO=$0
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to find a solution to cross-site origin problems on all subdomains for your domain, there's a much more robust answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39668584/1402498

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be specifying the origin incorrectly. Try this instead:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://video.xyz.example"`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this page by searching for my problem. It is also with subdomains, but also with different top level domains.

some-subdomains.GEMINI-next-Generation.House for English content
some-subdomains.GEMINI-next-Generation.Haus for German content

So the wildcard would have to be
https://*.GEMINI-next-Generation.H*

How to bring this in a header line?